# Replace empty list elements with pattern

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list which sometimes looks like:

```
list = {{},{}}
```

I need to catch these occurrences and replace them with {{0,0},0}.

The following hasn't worked

So,

```
If list==Null, list /. {{}, {}} -> {{0, 0}, 0},]
```

Comment: No need for the `If` statement the way you presented it. Simply `list /. {{}, {}} -> {{0, 0}, 0}` should do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Example**

```
data = {{{}, {}}, {{1, 2}, {1, 1}}, {{3, 3}, {4, 4}}};
data /. {{}, {}} -> {{0, 0}, 0}
```

**Output**

> {{{0, 0}, 0}, {{1, 2}, {1, 1}}, {{3, 3}, {4, 4}}}